# Windows Search, SQL query, local/remote

Tags: c#, .net, windows-search

I've installed Windows Search Service feature on Windows 2012. Now I'm testing form which should send query from Windows 2008 to Windows 2012 catalog. Windows 2008 has the Windows Search service installed too to get db driver installed/registered.

The form works properly only locally on Windows 2012
but doesn't work from Windows 2008 to Windows 2012 (remote access to catalog), Wireshark doesn't show outgoing query.

Query to local catalog (success):

```
("SELECT System.FileName,System.ItemPathDisplay,System.DateCreated FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:/test'", SearchConnect);
```

Queries to remote catalog Windows 2008 > Windows 2012 (no success)

```
("SELECT System.FileName,System.ItemPathDisplay,System.DateCreated FROM MyServer.SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:/test'", SearchConnect);
("SELECT System.FileName,System.ItemPathDisplay,System.DateCreated FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file://MyServer/C:/test'", SearchConnect);
```

Part of code - only select is modified during testing

```
 {
    string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO.1;Extended Properties='Application=Windows'";
    OleDbConnection SearchConnect = new OleDbConnection();
    SearchConnect.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    OleDbDataAdapter SearchAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT System.FileName,System.ItemPathDisplay,System.DateCreated FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:/test'", SearchConnect);

    SearchAdpt.Fill(searchResults);
  }
```

Reference

[MSDN - SCOPE and DIRECTORY Predicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking your local server to start a search on your local system to be done by another server ...

Use your statement with

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(externalServer,'script') T
```

Translates in your case in:

```
"SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyServer, ' SELECT System.FileName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.DateCreated FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE=''file:C:/test'' ') T"
```